# Place cube in structure-from-motion output Bundler and then determine the coordinates of a newly placed cube corners?

Tags: user-interface, 3d, bundler, meshlab, structure-from-motion

I have generated output of **structure-from-motion** system for unordered image collections by [Bundler](https://github.com/snavely/bundler_sfm).

Now I want to place a **cube** in the 3D generated space by some **GUI** and then get the **coordinates** of the **corners of the cube** in **world coordinate system**. The world coordinate system is determined in the Bundler itself and I want the points of the cube with respect to that.

What will be a good a way to procede? Also  I have **.ply** files generated by the **Bundler**.

I initially thought of loading the **bundle.out** file or **.ply** file in **meshlab** and then placing a cube, but I not able to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution using [Blender](https://www.blender.org/).

Here we can export the Bundler output using a script found [here](http://koelzk.crispy-cow.de/article/9/importing-bundler-scenes-to-blender).

Then just place a cube and then I am using a script to import the coordinates of the cube to a file. The script along with the previous one and also the complete project can be found [here](https://github.com/swapnil96/Camouflaging).